# ZEND, rendering different view with data

Tags: zend-framework, view, rendering

I have a problem as I want to render view from different controller and pass there datas. Do You know how to do it?

I was trying:

```
$this->renderScript('index/index.phtml')->entries = $result;
```

But my if:

```
if (count($this->entries) <= 0)
```

return 0

Do You know how to do it?
THANKS!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you mean you just want to render a different controller action's view script?

```
$this->view->entries = $result;
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('index/index', null, true);
```

Check out the manual page for the [ViewRenderer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer) helper.

Comment: what is the meaning of `,null, true` in this line: `$this->_helper->viewRenderer('index/index', null, true);` i look in documentation but didn't found out.

Comment: @DS9 It's a call to the `direct()` method which in turn calls `setRender()`. Second argument is `responseSegment` name, third is the `noController` boolean flag (doesn't attempt to prefix the path with the current controller name)

Answer (score 0):

Render view with action's output data.

in view page you wish to display data write this simple code.

```
echo $this->action('list','users','main');
```

**list** is my action name

**users** is my controller name

**main** is my module name (if module using in your project).