# In Zend MVC, how do you add a view for a page in a subpath?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, path, view, controller

/controller/action

but what if we have

/controller/action/subaction

How do you add this "subaction" to controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no sub-actions in an MVC design.

What you can do is set "subaction" as a parameter or argument to the action. If you don't want to use the default `param/value` pairing, you would need to set up a custom route to recognise a single value.

To choose a different view, you use the `ViewRenderer` action helper. See [ZEND, rendering different view with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856928/zend-rendering-different-view-with-data/4857115#4857115)

Answer (score 0):

you can create Facades somewhere else, then write mod_rewrite to redirect all ^/controller/.* URLs to /controller/ and redirect all requests in init() method to correspondent method in Facade

you can also try to create something like YourController that extends Zend_Controller_Action, and modify all controllers to extend that controller