# Zend Framework - How can I use the same view script with different actions in the controller?

Tags: zend-framework

My question basically is that I have lot of routes set up for CRUD operations. So inside the controller there are different action for Insert, Update, Delete and Select. 
For the Insert, Update and Delete I would like to use the same view script. Is that possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You simply set the view script name using the [`ViewRenderer`](http://zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer) action helper. For example

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('action');
```

**Edit:** If the view script is part of a different controller, see [ZEND, rendering different view with data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856928/283366)